# What is the best way to handle a page refresh using JWT and AngularJS to maintain user data

Tags: angularjs, jwt, local-storage

I am trying to work on best practise with implementing user authentication via JWTs from my back end server, and although I have it working, I just wanted clarification on something as there are many mixed reviews online.

After my user logs in, a JWT is sent back to my Angular App and then this token is sent back to my server to obtain the user's profile details.  Upon success, this JWT is stored in `localStorage`, a session is created and the user is redirected to the dashboard where they can move around the site freely.

However, when the page is refreshed, I grab the JWT from `localStorage` and pass it back to the server to obtain the user's profile details again (as I don't store any user data in storage). Although this works, there is a considerable delay whilst the app waits for the user data to be returned and re-creates the session. This is causing my application to show the login screen temporarily (as there is no authenticated user) and causing a very ugly user experience.

My question is what is the best practice around this scenario? Am I going about things the right/wrong way? Should I be storing any user data in storage?

I know there's probably similar questions, however, I can't find anything directly related to logging a user back in with a JWT whilst dealing with the login state.

Comment: I use an APP_INITIALIZER https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER to check if a token is stored, valid and to obtain the user profile before the app is starting. For your login screen, just redirect the user if he was logged in. because the initializer happens before the login page is shown and the login page is redirecting directly, a user with a valid token will never see the login

Comment: Thanks @x4rf41, but does this apply to AngularJS?  It looks like the APP_INITIALIZER is only present from v4 and up, or am I incorrect on this?

Comment: You are right. There are other solutions like this: https://tech.europace.de/angularjs-ordered-init-async-promise/ but imo they make things to complicated. why not just let the loading screen visible (with disabled inputs and a loading spinner) while the api call is being executed. This way it is also obvious to the user, that he is being logged in automatically. Another simple solution would be to show an overlay with a loader that hides the login screen while the api call is being executed

Comment: About the "best practice": I think there really is none in this case since angularjs does not provide a native feature for it. all other ways could be considered workarounds. simply pick what fits your application best (makes most sense to the user). You will find alot of different approaches when searching this site or the web

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @x4rf41 I am going to look at your ideas and find a way around this.